# C++ virtual destructor inheirtance from std::vector

Tags: c++, inheritance

So I'm studying for an C++ exam and I've come across the following question:

> If you were to inherit from `std::vector` would you create a virtual
>   destructor?

Since `std::vector` does not have a virtual destructor would there be any point in me creating one?

Comment: Inheriting from vector is discouraged in the first place, precisely for the lack of a virtual constructor. Use composition instead. For the sake of the question though: It depends if your class may become a polymorphic base class, i.e. whether current ot potential  future designs will use your class as a base in turn, and whether those derived objects will be accessed (and deleted) through your class pointer.

Comment: Making any destructor `virtual` won't cause any hurt unless you creat many many objects of that class. So consider the previous comment and go ahead.

Comment: The best answer is probably **I would not inherit from `std::vector`**. There are no valid reason to do that behind immediate laziness which will eventually lead to more maintenance.

Comment: There is no one answer to this without further context. It's a poor exam question.

Answer (score 1):

I think `std::vector` is a red herring. First let me rewrite the question as

> If you were to write a class `A` that inherits from `std::vector`, would you give it a virtual destructor?

Then the only relevant thing here is whether `std::vector` does already have a virtual destructor. If it had, the destructor of `A` would always be virtual automatically, no matter whether you specify it with the `virtual` keyword or not. But `std::vector` does *not* have a virtual destructor. So the reference to it can be dropped:

> If you were to write a class `A`, would you give it a virtual destructor?

The answer would still be that it will be automatically virtual if `A` inherits from any other class with virtual destructor, so the only interesting case left is:

> If you were to write a class `A`, which does not inherit from any class with virtual destructor, would you give it a virtual destructor?

Now this is a very general question and as mentioned in the comments, it depends on whether you intend to use the class as polymorphic base, i.e. whether you want to allow deletion of objects of a type derived from `A` through a pointer/reference to `A`.

Answer (score 1):

A class needs a virtual destructor if your design calls for deleting an object of a type derived from that class through a pointer to that class. That is,

```
class base {
};

class derived : public base {
};

void f() {
    base *bp = new derived;
    delete bp; // undefined behavior: base does not have a virtual destructor
}
```

`std::vector`, by design does not have a virtual destructor. It is not intended to be used as a base class.

So if your (flawed) design calls for deriving from `std::vector<whatever>` **and** deriving from your derived type **and** deleting objects of your ultimate type through pointers to your base type, then your base type must have a virtual destructor. But that has nothing to do with `std::vector` or with the fact that your base type is derived from `std::vector`. It's needed because of the way your base class is used.

Comment: This reminds me what [Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#virtual-dtor) thinks about virtual destructors in general.

Comment: @JónásBalázs -- unfortunately, the last line in the discussion that you link to is incorrect. "Had Base's destructor not been virtual, Derived's destructor would not have been called" -- maybe, but formally, the behavior us undefined. Full stop. Reasoning about what it might or might not do is pointless.